# Learning/implementing AngularJS before the upcoming 2.0 release

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The AngularJS core team announced that the upcoming version 2.0 won't just be adding a few new features here and there. The 2.0 update is meant to be an entire overhaul of how AngularJS works and it will be bringing with it a revolutionary change. The new release plans to deprecate a large portion of AngularJS. 1) Controllers. 2) DDO. 3) $scope 4) angular.module. 5) jqLite. What's left from the old releases? Not very much.

The core team also released an example of what AngularJS 2.0 will look like, in the most complex and over-engineered "Hello World" example ever: https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/examples/src/hello_world

What is the benefit of all this complexity? And what's the best way for someone to learn/implement AngularJS (before the release) when nearly half of the framework is about to be deprecated and the entire architecture will change?

Comment: Just because 2.0 is being released doesn't mean you have to switch to it immediately. I'd suggest keeping existing projects on 1.x, and then any new projects after 2.0 is released on 2.x.

Comment: 2.0 isn't coming out in the next week or month; it's coming out sometime next year. Don't wait to start learning it if you need it today.

Comment: Seems like there's a bit of bitterness in this question. It does suck a little, but a good place to start is reading the code. That hello world example is only really convoluted if you use Angular Dart (which I've never touched); the index_common file actually looks kind of like a C# class file, with its class attributes (using AtScript) and whatnot. I'm not sure how I feel about the syntax, but the code itself does make sense.

Comment: I agree with you that the new direction is not a good one. AngularJS has been an awesome technology and i use it on day to day basis. I love AnuglarJs because it is very easy to bootstrap (for me at least), and it is opinionated in the right place and the right time AND lets me to do my business logic the way I want including how I structure my code and bootstrapping logic.   However, it seems like they are trying so hard to push some of the Google polymer technologies into it and it the process they are trying it to change Angular drastically but not in a good way.

Comment: 2.0 won't be out till late next year. I'd recommend watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNmWybAyBHI&app=desktop. I wouldn't take much from that "Hello World" example. The thing that you have to realise is that web browser technologies are changing at a rapid rate and frameworks such as Angular need to change with them. As a web developer you learn to learn new tech all the time. I would encourage you to learn how to keep learning new frameworks and technologies.

Comment: sounds  bit like "don't ever buy a new car, tv or phone... next year there will be a better version". oh and the following years too

Comment: Buckle up. You are in a rapidly evolving field. Until web technology itself goes through an overhaul, you will continue to see various web frameworks (not technology) come abound. AngularJS 2.0 is yet another such new web framework, albeit with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not like the changes they're implementing then simply just don't update your Angular app.

I myself just finished a large project in Angular and will need to continue supporting and editing it, but I'm not about to refactor all my codebase just because a new version is out there. Angular's documentation will still be available for 1.2.x and I'll continue to reference that and other resources.

Comment: Hard to define when 1.x will become obsolete... Everything seems to be working fine and I have not yet run into a problem I or others can't solve. Weighing the amount of time to learn the complete rewrite of the 2.0 structure and the time we can spend just working on our app we're not going to bother fixing something that's not broken. Maybe some time down the road we might revisit this, but for now I believe it's not worth it right now.

Answer (score -1):

Software innovation brings AngularJS 2.0 supporting [ECMAScript 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript), which "adds significant new syntax for writing complex applications, including classes and modules".  Since I began watching Joe Eames' Pluralsight tutorial on "Building AngularJS and Node.js Apps with the MEAN Stack", I'm a .NET convert.  It's interesting how fast I can run the SDLC via PaaS (heroku + Git) and iterate to build up a killer web app.